# Sencha Touch proxy send post request with dynamic arguments

Tags: sencha-touch, sencha-touch-2

I want to send post request in sencha touch and the arguments I want to post are dynamic i.e. I want to take the textField values as a parameters to post. Please help me

```
proxy: {
     type: "ajax",
        url:'http://anotherserver.com/query.php',
        method:'post',
    extraParams: {
        val: "TextField1.Text" // **here I want to provide the value of the textField help me plz**
    },
    reader: {
        type: "json",
        rootProperty: "notes",
        totalProperty: "total"
    }
},
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Usually you want to wrap the text field inside a form (formpanel).
Then you can use

```
var form = Ext.Viewport.down('.formpanel'),
    values = form.getValues(),
    textfieldValue = values.textfield_name;
...
extraParams: {
    val: textfieldValue
},
```

Answer (score 1):

Look first for Sencha Touch model concept because your can tag along your model into your Form (Ext.FormPanel) and treat it as one.

```
var model = Ext.create('Ext.data.Model',{
    fields: ['name', 'email', 'password'],
    proxy: [] //your proxy settings here,
    customFunctionWithAjax: function(){
    }

});

var form = Ext.create('Ext.form.Panel', {
    fullscreen: true,
    items: [
        {
            xtype: 'textfield',
            name: 'name',
            label: 'Name'
        },
        {
            xtype: 'emailfield',
            name: 'email',
            label: 'Email'
        },
        {
            xtype: 'passwordfield',
            name: 'password',
            label: 'Password'
        }
    ]
});
//after filling up your form you can get all textfields value 
//with .getValues() and set it to your model

model.setData(form.getValues);  
//then you can do anything you want like SAVE, or update
model.save();
//or call your custom function with your customised ajax request
model.customFunctionWithAjax(); 
// you can also check if your data are correct before sending it using .validate();
model.validate();
```